# Tfs build definition

Tags: deployment, tfs, tfsbuild, alm, tfvc

I am thinking to implement branching of the source code for release build which is currently happening from main trunk. So the way it will be structured is below

Release
    UAT-sprint01
           Source
           Common
           Web

UAT-sprint02
           Source
           Common
           Web

I got the build definition that does the job and it deploys from main trunk. I am looking to update build definition so that it could pick up the latest one from release branch and does the build/deployment. It should also have the provision to pass the release branch version in case I want to deploy any particular one.

Comment: Your build process should not be responsible for deploying software.

Answer (score 1):

You sold move your deployment to a release management tool rather than a build tool.

You can use octopus deploy or release manager for visual Studio to deploy you software in a release pipeline.

http://nakedalm.com/blog/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/